# closed form for $ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^k k^k}{k!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, closed-form, lambert-w

After I already got great help with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477544/sequence-a-sum-k-0n-fracxkkfn-k) I now have the follow-up-question of whether there is a closed form for $$f_n(x) =  \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^k k^k}{k!}$$ or $ \ \ \ \ \ g_n(x) =  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k (n-k)^k}{k!} \ \ \ \ \ $ respectively for which (negative) $x$ the function $g_n(x)$ eventually becomes negative.

I tried $$g_n(x) =  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{k}  {{k}\choose{j}} n^{k-j} (-k)^j = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{k}  \frac{(-kx)^j}{j!} \frac{(nx)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}  $$

but that led nowhere as well as splitting up $f_n$ as

$$
f_n(x)=\sum \limits_{s=0}^{ \left \lfloor n/2 \right \rfloor} \frac{x^{2s}}{2s!} \left ( (n-2s)^{2s} - \frac{(n-1-2s)^{2s+1} x}{2s+1}\right ).
$$

Edit:

Thanks for pointing at the lambert W function, I now came up with
$$ f_\infty(x) = - \sum \limits_{n=1}^{ \infty} \sum \limits_{k=n}^{ \infty} \frac{(-k)^{k-1}}{k!} (-x)^k,
$$
which is great because x is negative.

Comment: have you tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: By the Lagrange inversion formula, $f_\infty$ is clearly related with the Lambert $W$ function, but the partial sums... they're just polynomials.

Comment: Yes I tried wolfram alpha but because the index k is not the same through all iterations it proves rather difficult (at least for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)
$$ f_\infty(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n x^n}{n!} = -\frac{W(-x)}{1+W(-x)} $$
holds for any $x<e^{-1}$, where $W$ is Lambert function, the inverse function of $xe^x$.
Over such range we simply have $\text{sign}\,f_\infty(x) = \text{sign}(x)$, since $f_\infty$ is increasing and $f_\infty(0)=0$.
The previous formula also tells us that $f_\infty(x)$, despite being given by a not-so-fast-convergent series, can be numerically computed in a pretty effective way through Netwton's method.

As a reference, you may consider the formula $(14)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) and [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) about $W$.

What is the reason leading to the study of the partial sums of such series?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! But I'm sorry to say that I don't understand the second part of the equation. Sure I can accept that $W(x) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!} x^n$, but I don't see the equation becoming $\frac{W(-x)}{1+ W(-x)}$. Also is there any possibility to know if $f_n(x) = \frac{e^{n x} \Gamma(n,nx)}{(n-1)!}$? 

The background is that I try to calculate a spiral in the context of "a fire fighter's problem".

Comment: @justabit: take formula $(14)$, replace $x$ by $-x$, apply $\frac{d}{dx}$, multiply by $x$.